# Leak and What to Do About It

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-leaks

According to Instruments the following has a leak and I don't understand why.  Can anyone assist with this?  Any help appreciated.  Thank you.

```
- (User *) findUser:(NSString *)userName
{
    NSFetchRequest *userFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
    [userFetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName = %@", userName]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedUser = [[self context] executeFetchRequest:userFetch error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"findUser Error: %@", error);
        return nil;
    }
    else if ([fetchedUser count] < 1)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([fetchedUser count] != 1)   // should always be zero or 1.
        {
            return nil;
        }

        User *user = (User *)[fetchedUser objectAtIndex:0];
        return user;
    }
}
```

The call happens here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    . . .

   NSString *uName = ((User *)[currentUserList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).userName;
   uManager.userObj = [svoDataHelper findUser:uName];
   [detail didSelectUserWithName:[uManager userName]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very verbose. Try this just after fetching: (I'm using `result` instead of `fetchedUser`).

```
return result.count == 1 ? result.firstObject : nil;
```

The leak is likely happening elsewhere, most likely in your opaque data helper and data manager classes. One strategy is to try to do the fetch in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead and see if you still get the leak.

Comment: Yeah, that code is awfully wordy -- it was really intended as a stub as I had planned to do some error handling when I wrote it.  Anyway, thanks for the idea on moving the fetch to try it.  Hadn't thought of that; I'll check it out.